# Sending an HTTP POST request through the android emulator doesn't work

Tags: java, android, http, tomcat, android-emulator

I'm running a tomcat servlet on my local machine and an Android emulator with an app that makes a post request to the servlet. The code for the POST is below (without exceptions and the like):

```
        String strUrl = "http://10.0.2.2:8080/DeviceDiscoveryServer/server/devices/";
        Device device = Device.getUniqueInstance();

        urlParameters += URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(device.getUser(), "UTF-8");
        urlParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("port", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(new Integer(Device.PORT).toString(), "UTF-8");
        urlParameters += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("address", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(device.getAddress().getHostAddress(), "UTF-8");

        URL url = new URL(strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoOutput(true);
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(urlParameters);
        wr.flush();
        wr.close();
```

Whenever this code is executed, the servlet isn't called. However if I change the type of the request to 'GET' and don't write anything to the outputstream, the servlet gets called and everything works fine. Am I just not making the POST correctly or is there some other error?

Comment: you should instead check your servlet code. It should accept POST requests.

Comment: The servlet works. See below, I found a solution that works. I don't know why though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity I tried getting the response code for my request:

```
int responseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);
```

This actually made the request go through and I got 200. I checked my Tomcat logs and the request finally got handled. I guess doing `url.openConnection()` and writing to the `OutputStream` isn't enough.

Answer (score 1):

try the following code, it may help u

```
        try
{
    String argUrl = 
        "";

    String requestXml = "";
    URL url = new URL( argUrl );
    URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
    System.out.println("STRING" + requestXml);
    // specify that we will send output and accept input
    con.setDoInput(true);
    con.setDoOutput(true);

    con.setConnectTimeout( 20000 );  // long timeout, but not infinite
    con.setReadTimeout( 20000 );

    con.setUseCaches (false);
    con.setDefaultUseCaches (false);

    // tell the web server what we are sending
    con.setRequestProperty ( "Content-Type", "text/xml" );

    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter( con.getOutputStream() );
    writer.write( requestXml );
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    // reading the response
    InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader( con.getInputStream() );

    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
    char[] cbuf = new char[ 2048 ];
    int num;

    while ( -1 != (num=reader.read( cbuf )))
    {
        buf.append( cbuf, 0, num );
    }

    String result = buf.toString();
    System.err.println( "\nResponse from server after POST:\n" + result );
}
catch( Throwable t )
{
    t.printStackTrace( System.out );
}
```